# WordPress as a headless CMS with Next.js - problem to rendering a post content with code highlights snippets

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, wordpress-rest-api, headless

Currently, the post content is rendering well, but I couldn't make works the code highlights that I have on my post as examples.
I'm using WordPress GraphQL backend and Next.js to front. I'm following this tutorial: https://dev.to/kendalmintcode/using-wordpress-as-a-headless-cms-with-next-js-2h5p
But the fact is that my blog has some code examples that I want to show with highlights. Like this one: https://fl4v.io/for-loop-learn-how-you-can-use-it/
At the moment, I'm doing like this:

```html
<div>
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postData.content }}
              
</div>
```

following my post full script:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
// data
import { getAllPostsWithSlug, getPost } from "../../lib/api";

export default function Post({ postData }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (!router.isFallback && !postData?.slug) {
    return <p>hmm...looks like an error</p>;
  }

  const formatDate = (date) => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);

    return `${newDate.getDate()}/${
      newDate.getMonth() + 1
    }/${newDate.getFullYear()}`;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>{postData.title}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        {router.isFallback ? (
          <h2>Loading...</h2>
        ) : (
          <article>
            <div>
              <h1>{postData.title}</h1>
              <p>{formatDate(postData.date)}</p>
            </div>
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postData.content }}
              className="
                        text-justify
                        p-5"
            />
          </article>
        )}
        <p>
          <Link href="/blog">
            <a>back to articles</a>
          </Link>
        </p>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const allPosts = await getAllPostsWithSlug();

  return {
    paths: allPosts.edges.map(({ node }) => `/blog/${node.slug}`) || [],
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const data = await getPost(params.slug);

  return {
    props: {
      postData: data.post,
    },
  };
}
```

Any suggestion to solve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can easily find code example in post content(if it is wrapped in pre or something) you can use a library called `html-react-parser` which basically can enable you to wrap an element with react component. Then you could use CodeMirror or some highlighter lib to generate code section.